# Is there an easy way in ruby to split an array of hashes into mutiple arrays by common key?

Tags: arrays, ruby

If I have an array like this:

```
[{:x=>1, :y=>a, :z=>i}, {:x=>2, :z=>ii}, {:x=>3, :y=>b, :z=>iii}, {:x=>4, :z=>iv}, {:x=>5, :y=>c, :z=>v}]
```

Is there an easy one liner to get arrays for each common key like this?:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [a, b, c], [i, ii, iii, iv, v]]
```

Comment: Are `a`, `ii`, etc. variables or methods (or strings  or symbols, in which case they should be writted `"a"` or `:a`)?

Comment: When you give an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input value (e.g.,  `arr = [{:x=>1,....`). That way readers can refer to those variables (`arr`) in answers and comments without having to define them. Moreover, everyone will use the same variable when referencing those objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a variable pointing to your array:

```
arr = [{:x=>1, :y=>a, :z=>i}, {:x=>2, :z=>ii}, {:x=>3, :y=>b, :z=>iii}, {:x=>4, :z=>iv}, {:x=>5, :y=>c, :z=>v}]
```

Then you can write it like this:

```
%i{x y z}.map { |key| arr.map { |subarr| subarr[key] }.compact }
```

Comment: My only suggestion is to replace `%i{x y z}` with an array computed from `arr`, considering that `arr`'s keys may be determined dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I think there would be a fist fight if you ever tried to submit this as production code, but it does the trick even if you don't know the keys in advance.

```
arr = [{:x=>1, :y=>'a', :z=>'i'}, {:x=>2, :z=>'ii'}, {:x=>3, :y=>'b', :z=>'iii'}, {:x=>4, :z=>'iv'}, {:x=>5, :y=>'c', :z=>'v'}]

arr.each_with_object({}) {|h,o| h.each { |k,v| (o[k] ||= []) << v}}.values
```

Comment: Good answer. It's worth a mention that this could alternatively be written `arr.each.with.object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |h,o| h.each { |k,v| o[k] << v }}.values`.  Neither is better. In my experience your way tends to be a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [{:x=>1, :y=>'a', :z=>'i'}, {:x=>2, :z=>'ii'}, {:x=>3, :y=>'b', :z=>'iii'},
       {:x=>4, :z=>'iv'}, {:x=>5, :y=>'c', :z=>'v'}]

keys = arr.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
  #=> [:x, :y, :z]

arr.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }.transpose.map(&:compact)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", "b", "c"], ["i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"]]
```

After computing `keys`, three steps follow.

```
a = arr.map { |h| h.values_at(*keys) }
  #=> [[1, "a", "i"], [2, nil, "ii"], [3, "b", "iii"], [4, nil, "iv"], [5, "c", "v"]]
b = a.transpose
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", nil, "b", nil, "c"], ["i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"]]
b.map(&:compact)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["a", "b", "c"], ["i", "ii", "iii", "iv", "v"]]
```